# GraphQL over REST?

Tags: rest, web-applications, graphql

I see many debates/discussion over google about GraphQL over REST. But my point  - Is n't the GraphQL endpoint in itself a Rest endpoint and controller ?
This seems to be verified from example given at this [GraphQL tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=zX2I7-aIldE) (See either at 23m or 9.30m). So is n't graphql
also served over REST ? I see the verbs used in this example is POST(32:30 m) instead of verbs Query or mutuation . Are `Query` or `Mutation` is not mandatory ?

Also is rest query need to be JSON string or it has its own syntax or it supports both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GraphQL specification only defines a query language to get the data. It does not define how the external client access the GraphQL service over the Internet.It is up to the server implementation to decide which protocol to use .Almost all server will simply choose to use the HTTP.

So in the end , you still have to implement a HTTP endpoint in order to receive GraphQL query. That HTTP endpoint then pass the received GraphQL query to the GraphQL engine to process and return back the result to the client. The author in that youtube video is just showing he chooses to implement the GraphQL endpoint using `@RestController`. In Java world , you can simply use [this](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-servlet) and [this](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-spring) for the GraphQL endpoint if you do not want to roll out by yourself.

Implementing a HTTP endpoint using `@RestController` does not mean that it is a REST service if you are not implementing them based on REST principle. Following the same logic, using `@RestController` to implement a GraphQL endpoint does not mean that GraphQL is a REST . Moreover , in GraphQL world , there is only one endpoint for all resources which is totally difference in REST while each resource has their own endpoint.

> Are Query or Mutation is not mandatory ?

For Mutation , the word `Mutation` is mandatory. If there is no `Query` or `Mutation` , it is treated it as `Query`.

> Also is rest query need to be JSON string or it has its own syntax or
>   it supports both ?

The query is not a JSON .It is the GraphQL query which the syntax is defined in the GraphQL specification.

Comment: You said `The query is not a JSON .It is the GraphQL ...`  But at the second link you mentioned it says  `1. GET request with query, operationName and variables parameters. The variable parameters are json encoded
2. POST request with body application/json and keys query (string),` I am not sure what json encoded parameters mean in GET request and what  body application/json in POST request ? Doesn't it mean json format ?

Comment: Yes. The POST request is a JSON which contain the fields `query` , `operationName` and `variables` . But the value of the  `query` field is not a JSON but a GraphQL query which has its own syntax. I realise you are asking the content of the query field . For example , it can be `query { employee {id name}}`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `I realise you are answer the content of this query field` ?

Comment: i have a typo , i mean I think you are asking if the content of the `query` field in the POST request  is a JSON string